# Windows 7 - remembering past search terms in the start menu. Was I imagining this?

Tags: windows-7, search, start-menu

I seem to remember windows 7 being able to remember search strings you've typed in the start menu's search bar.   I tend to use that bar to run commands (because it's slightly more convenient than clicking on 'run' and typing your command there).  One particular example of that is connecting to computers with mstsc command.    I seem to remember on someone else's computer that it would bring up a list of recently typed mstsc commands (useful if you use this to connect to many different computers) when you would begin typing mstsc in the search bar.

I know the run edit box has this feature but does the search bar also have it?   All it seems to do on my current incarnation of W7 is search for items based on what you've typed so far.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have never seen the search bar perform this function... only the run box :(

Comment: Sorry William, shouldn't this be a comment instead an answear?

Comment: @DiogoRocha Actually it is an answer based on experience and William has plenty.

Comment: @DiogoRocha Nope, as Moab said, it was an answer - the question wasn't asking for alternatives (after all, the run box does this), he was just asking about the actual search box - and it doesn't... also, AFAIK, it isn't possible to extend it. ... It does remember some last programs, but not switches that are used on them, so, I don't think it is possible to get what the question asker wants at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are thinking of the search box in windows explorer that has this new feature?
Its only in win7 professional and greater. Here's a [good summmary](http://www.mydigitallife.info/delete-or-disable-recent-search-entries-history-in-windows-7-explorer-search-box/).